# jupyter notebook can't be saved from the remote access

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I run a jupyter notebook which can access from the remote IP on our lab server(Of course I visited from the intranet of the school). And everything seems ok.

However, when I create a test.ipynb from the remote IP and write sth and save finally, nothing happens but autosave failed.
But the question is I can access the jupyter server from the lab server via localhost like.
And the save operation work!

I don't know why this happens??

I've tried to use chomd to add permissions, but it doesn't work.
And I've tried to use a docker to provide jupyter server, but it doesn't work either.
It seems to encounter some network problems that I never meet before.

Is that sth wrong with the lab server?